# GAPI: Failed to request report data and provides no further information

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api-js-client

We're using the **PHP GAPI** ([https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) to retrieve data and to show graphs in admin panel of our websites.

We know this library hasn’t been updated since 2009, but it was working fine for us for a long time until some months ago...

Bellow is the error we got :

```
Fatal error:
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to request report data.
Error: "Request failed, fopen provides no further information"' in /www/clientname/site/lacentrale/gapi.class.php:218

Stack trace:
#0 /www/clientname/site/cms/include.dashboard.analytics.visits.php(37): gapi->requestReportData('95220065', Array, Array, Array, NULL, '2014-11-23', '2014-12-22', 1, 30)
...
#6 {main} thrown in /www/clientname/site/cms/gapi.class.php on line 218
```

Here is the code for *include.dashboard.analytics.visits.php* — lines 35 to 39 (error on line 37):

```
if ( ! $ga = $myCache->getCache() ){
    $ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);
    $ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array($dimension),array('visits','pageviews','timeOnSite','avgTimeOnSite','pageviewsPerVisit'),array($dimension),null,$begin,$end,1,$max);
    $myCache->saveCache($ga);
}
```

And here is the code for *gapi.class.php* — lines 212 to 219 (error on line 218):

```
if(substr($response['code'],0,1) == '2')
{
  return $this->reportObjectMapper($response['body']);
}
else 
{
  throw new Exception('GAPI: Failed to request report data. Error: "' . strip_tags($response['body']) . '"');
}
```

We don’t fully understand these errors which are not so clear, and as nothing changed in these files...

As we seen on other StackOverflow tickets and other forums, we've already checked our profile ID which is the good one (8 digits after the p in the Google Analytics URL).

We would like to not move to another PHP API for GA (if any other available? what would be the best solution as of today?) because it would required a lot a work to implement again the admin panel we've made ...

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : we had made modifications into the *gapi.class.php* file since a long time for a project which required special securised specifications for server connection and we were still using this file modified in other projects which do not required this modifications...

So we downloaded a clean copy of GAPI and replaced with the initial file to solve the problem ;-)